# how to remove this notice while displaying the result in php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have connected sqlserver using ODBC in php. I'm able to connect the database and query it, but in the result part I'm not getting proper results.

I'm getting this notice:

```
 server connected
 Notice: Use of undefined constant CName - assumed 'CName' in      
 D:\Installations\wamp\www\connectweb\newfile.php on line 21
 Turmeric 
  Notice: Use of undefined constant CName - assumed 'CName' in    
  D:\Installations\wamp\www\connectweb\newfile.php on line 21
 Neem 
 Notice: Use of undefined constant CName - assumed 'CName' in   
 D:\Installations\wamp\www\connectweb\newfile.php on line 21
 Coriander 
  Notice: Use of undefined constant CName - assumed 'CName' in    
  D:\Installations\wamp\www\connectweb\newfile.php on line 21
 Almond
```

This is my code:

```
     <?php

      $connect = odbc_connect('ServerDB','sa', 'admin');

     if (!$connect) {
    die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
    }
      else
    echo "server connected";
      $query = "SELECT CName FROM dbo.Conc";
      $result = odbc_exec($connect, $query);

    while(odbc_fetch_row($result)){
      $name= odbc_result($result,CName);
    echo("$name  \n");
     }

   ?>
```

I'm new to php and I don't know where I'm stuck. The `dbo.Conc` table has a field `CName`. I'm connecting to the database using odbc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From PHP docs:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-result.php)

The second argument for odbc_result:

> The field name being retrieved. It can either be an integer containing
>   the column number of the field you want; or it can be a string
>   containing the name of the field.

What you need to do is this:

```
$name= odbc_result($result,'CName');
```

Comment: @Akshara - if you meant CName to be a variable instead a string, make sure you fix the syntax and define it. Please don't take the out of sight, out of mind approach by lowering the reporting level. if you just want a string that identifies the column, look at what xbonez answered.